# Why do <S-Left> and some other keys not work in vim under tmux?

Tags: key-bindings, terminal, tmux

I know at least about [`<S-Left>`](https://vimhelp.org/motion.txt.html#%3CS-Left%3E), [`<S-Right>`](https://vimhelp.org/motion.txt.html#%3CS-Right%3E), [`<C-Left>`](https://vimhelp.org/motion.txt.html#%3CC-Left%3E), [`<C-Rigth>`](https://vimhelp.org/motion.txt.html#%3CC-Right%3E). But I guess there are others.

I'm mostly interested in the **why**. Because knowing a reason often makes finding a solution easy. But if you provide some solutions that would be a useful bonus.

Steps to reproduce:

```
$ vim -u NONE +'se nocompatible'
:some cmd<S-Left>
```

After pressing `<S-Left>` it blinks (visual bell), and exits the Cmdline mode.

Comment: Um, they all work fine for me. What happens when you use them?

Comment: @BLayer I added steps to reproduce to the question. Try `<S-Left>`. If it moves one word backwards, tell me your `TERM` please, and what escape sequence `<S-Left>` produces.

Comment: @x-yuri Do they work for you under **g**vim? What about a different terminal? I'd guess that would help you find your answer.

Comment: Your help links are for the Normal mode commands but your example is for Command-line mode. Anyways my TERM value is `xterm-256color`. My `<S-Left>` shows `^[[1;2D` (first character, `^[`, is Escape). Everything is the same whether I'm in tmux or terminal without tmux.

Comment: Have you seen this? [How to get shift+arrows and ctrl+arrows working in Vim in tmux?](https://superuser.com/questions/401926)

Comment: @BLayer That's it. My `TERM=screen` (the default in `tmux`). And do note that supported values are [`screen`, `tmux` and derivatives](https://man.archlinux.org/man/community/tmux/tmux.1.en#default-terminal).

Comment: "That's it"... ? Did you get it working? And, yeah, I'm aware of that documentation but `xterm-256color` works perfectly well for me so that's what I use. If it ain't broke...

Comment: @BLayer By "that's it" I meant that we now know why it works for you.